# Write temperature data from multiple esp8266 (node MCU) to single database without internet

Tags: esp8266

I am currently working on a project to read temperatures from multiple points using a sensor and Node MCU setup. I require all these datas (from 16 node MCU) to be stored to a web server. Can I do it without internet. I don't want to do live monitoring but have to store data for few days in the server. I have a Raspberry pi that can be used to create the wifi hotspot and a repeater to extend the range. 
Sorry if the post is confusing. I am a beginner in this field. Can I implement this? If yes can anyone please outline the steps to be followed?

Comment: Why do you think you would need an internet connection?

Comment: Since I have multiple node MCU, I thought i may require Internet. Can you please guide me with the steps?

Comment: do not confuse local area network (LAN) with the internet

Comment: If you need data to be "stored to a web server", then by definition you will ultimately at some point need an internet connection.  If by "web sever"  you just mean a database server on your local network, then an internet connection is not required and you can just have everything connected together on a LAN via a WiFi access point.

Comment: If I make a local server database using xamp, mysql and apache, will i be able to connect multiple node MCU and update the database?

Comment: If everything is on the same local network, then yes, the NodeMCUs will be able to communicate with the local apache installation and subsequently make updates to the local database.  A connection the the internet would not be required in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to create a Hotspot in Raspberry PI i.e WAP(Wireless access point) and gonna connect all 16 NodeMCUs to it you will have to transform your Raspberry PI into a solid LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) system with one apt-get invocation. Google Search "Building LAMP server on Raspberry Pi".

Xampp is for the Intel-based computers not ARM Linux based. There is no way you will get it to run on Raspberry Pi.

And If you are just going to connect your 16 NodeMCU to Raspberry PI WAP and then send the data received by Rasberry Pi to the PC having XAMPP on it, it will be difficult and complicated for you.